# ie only style with min width

Tags: css, media-queries

How do I combine an ie only media query with a min width media query (I read IE is the only browser that won't support nested media queries) - for ie I use

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {}
```

So I thought I could do

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {}
```

But this is still being applied below `1024px`.  How do I combine the min width and ie media queries so it is only applied above 1024px in ie?

(I was going to make a snippet but they don't work in ie anyway so let me know if you need more info, but the above code is enough to replicate my problem)

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but don't you also need to check the min-width on the second query `(-ms-high-contrast: ...) and (min-width:...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a comma, which acts like an `or`

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), 
                  (-ms-high-contrast: none) {}
```

so the mediaquery is triggered when

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active)
```

or

```
(-ms-high-contrast: none)
```

if you want to add another condition you need to add it twice

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (-ms-high-contrast: active), 
       screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {}
```

---

<sub>(*not sure if you need to also check the `screen` twice, I've included after @04FS comment below*)</sub>

Comment: ah, stupid blind copy and pasting - never knew commas in media queries meant a separate query, will accept when it lets me, thanks!

Comment: Should `screen` not also be added twice then? Otherwise, the second part would apply to _any_ media. (Not sure if that is relevant for their situation, or if it might be relevant to what makes this hack work in the first place.)

Comment: think that's what confused me as the screen wasn't in the second part so just thought it was part of the same media query, thanks again